# Execute PHP in Category/Tag description

Tags: php, wordpress

We all know that there are plenty of plugins and hacks that allows execution of PHP in posts/pages and sidebars.
But how to execute PHP in category/tag description in WordPress?

I simply want to allow PHP codes in category/tag description so that I can show them in Category/Tags pages like `<?php echo category_description(); ?>`.

[image]

Comment: explain your question or give any example or show your code you are trying

Comment: I simply want to allow PHP codes in category/tag description so that I can show them in Category/Tags pages like <?php echo category_description(); ?>

Comment: I have added my answer you can check with that

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

By Default when `category_description()` gets called, it is filtered by code.
But I suggest you to remove filter by adding them in functions.php of theme. Try something like this. I use it for html tags

```
remove_filter( 'pre_term_description', 'wp_filter_kses' );
remove_filter( 'term_description', 'wp_kses_data' );
```

Comment: I'm afraid that I couldn't explain my quesiton in details.
I want to execute php code in category/tags description editor. See screenshot: http://prntscr.com/4q5m9t

Comment: You need to parse this php code using `eval` or go through with this http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, without headaches, is to use a shortcode and send all variables as attributes, like:

> Description of the category: [php var1="33" var2="string" var3="array&array&array"]shortcode content[/php].

And then parse all the `$atts` and content doing any PHP you want. To enable shortcodes in the category description, use:

```
add_filter( 'category_archive_meta', function( $content ){
    return apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
});
```

A test shortcode:

```
add_shortcode( 'php', function( $atts, $content ){
    return sprintf( 
        "<pre><code>%s\n\n%s</code></pre>", 
        $content, 
        print_r( $atts, true ) 
    );
});
```

And the result using the sample description above:

<kbd>[image: shortcode php]</kbd>

Comment: Can u plz brief it little more.
What I want is: include php files with query string in category/tag description so that I have not to update category/tag description content each time it is updated (like live scores).

Comment: Did you notice that I improved your question with pieces of information you left in comments? You could do the same...